# Composer for autoloading php

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

Hi i have this folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

I'm using composer for autoloading my files but it is dont work .. i do it first time and i dont know how to implement this.

My composer.json

```
{
"name": "Some name",
"description": "Some Framework",
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"license": "proprietary",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Some names of authors",
        "email": "some@gmail.com"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Apison": "/../sdk/"
    }
}
```

}

And my index.php

```
    <?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Apison\Sdk\App();
```

When i update my composer it will write: Nothing to load and PHP will catch exeption on line with `$app = new \Apison\Sdk\App();`

Thanks for your tips

Comment: `/../sdk/` --- this path points to the root of your filesystem. Open your terminal and try `ls /../sdk/`

Comment: so my path is `sdk/`?

Comment: yes i mean it work: Composer catch this error: `A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator.` Thanks it is move forward :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespaces need `\\`:

```
"Apison\\": "../sdk"
```

documentation:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

---

Based on our chat, the solution is this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Apison\\Sdk\\": "sdk"
    }
}
```

Then the namespaces and file structure was changed to comply with the [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard

Comment: then run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: it is not work :/ and i m using coposer dump-autoload

Comment: i m read this documentation.. i do it like examples and this is not work i dont know where i have mistake

Comment: like this? `"Apison\\": "../sdk"`?

Comment: try moving the sdk directory into the same directory as composer.json. then change the autoload to "Apison\\": "sdk" - to rule out directory location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69971/discussion-between-user3355351-and-m79lkm).